# get a member value for a key date in the selected period

Tags: mdx

I need a special member value in a mdx: In the command below I select data for customers. The result shows the amounts per month for the customers within customergroup, customer ID with name and the customer level. The customer level will change within the periods.

Now what i want to have is the customer level on key date i.e. '13.July 2013'. Any idea how i can filter this value.?

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Amount1]
   ,[Measures].[Amount2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Group ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Name].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Level].Children*
      [Time].[Month].Children
  )
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-05-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-12-01T00:00:00]
     ,
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2012-05-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2012-12-01T00:00:00]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [MyCube]
);
```

Comment: ...so Amount1 and Amount2 should only be the sum for the 13th July 2013?

Comment: The amounts should be the summary of the period ( 1.5.2013 - 1.12.2013). I need only the [Customer Level] for the key date (13.Jul.2013). Thanks.

Comment: And for other dates,,it needs to be blank?

Comment: Hi, each customer has his own value on 13.July and i have to use this value over the total period.

Comment: This `( 1.5.2013 - 1.12.2013)` disagrees with the date ranges in the sub-select? Why are there 2012 dates in the sub-select?

Comment: (still a bit unclear exactly what you want)

Comment: Hi, we compare two periods. The [Customer Level] is like a status which can change every day. Therfore we need this value only for a key date/ target date within the selected periods.

Comment: Did my answer help you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom sets. If you only want customers who have activity on `13.July 2013` then something like the following is a start:

```
WITH SET [X] AS
    NonEmpty(
       [Dim Customer].[Customer Level].Children
      ,([Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-07-01T00:00:00])
    )
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Amount1]
   ,[Measures].[Amount2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Group ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Name].Children*
      [X]*
      [Time].[Month].Children
  )
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-05-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-12-01T00:00:00]
     ,
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2012-05-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2012-12-01T00:00:00]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [MyCube]
);
```

Comment: I´m sorry that i didn´t write any answer but the project is on hold at the moment.

Comment: @Katharina321 no problem. We will be interested to see your solution once done.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is ok, you want to display the level **only** when the date is `13th July 2013` and otherwise keep it blank. Leveraging the year-month-date hierarchy you have, you can try the below code:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Dim Customer].[Customer Level].[Required Level] AS
IIF
    (
     [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-07-13T00:00:00]
     ,NonEmpty
            (
             [Dim Customer].[Customer Level].CHILDREN,
             [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-07-13T00:00:00]
            )
     ,NULL
    )

SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Amount1]
   ,[Measures].[Amount2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Group ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Name].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Level].[Required Level]*
      HIERARCHIZE
        (
          {
           [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Month].Children
           +
           [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-07-13T00:00:00]
          }
        )

  )
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-05-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-12-01T00:00:00]
     ,
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2012-05-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2012-12-01T00:00:00]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [MyCube]
);
```

**2nd approach** - calculating them separately and combining the results

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Amount1]
   ,[Measures].[Amount2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Group ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Name].Children*
      NULL*
      [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Month].Children
  )
  +
 NonEmpty
  (
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Group ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Name].Children*
      [Dim Customer].[Customer Level].CHILDREN*
      [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-07-13T00:00:00]
  )                

  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-05-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2013-12-01T00:00:00]
     ,
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2012-05-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2012-12-01T00:00:00]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [MyCube]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for proposal.